# How to use Runnable Method?

Tags: java, java-threads

I am currently working on a little game I've made and I want to use a jump() method and I want to use it as a Thread. But I have little experience with Threads therefore the game aka the JFrame won't pop up when I use the Thread. But I am already using a Thread to run the class where this method is located, so maybe that causes issues.

```
public Runnable jump() {
    for (;;) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            for (int i = 0; i < pressedKeys.size(); i++) {
                if (pressedKeys.get(i).equals("space") && j == 0) {
                    player.move(0, -60);
                    j++;
                    pressedKeys.remove("space");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Method I am trying to run with a Thread.
In the main class is use these Threads to run.

```
    Thread t3 = new Thread(movement);
    t3.start();
    Thread th4 = new Thread(movement.jump());
    th4.start();
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Did you check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html? Especially https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-. Also your question itself cannot be answered, it's missing what player.move is supposed to do. Any minimal reproducible example would help.

Answer (score 1):

Runnable is an interface like this:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Runnable{
    public void run();
}
```

You need to create a class that implements Runnable:

```java
public class YourRunnable{
    @Override
    public void run(){
        //Your code
    }
}
```

After that, you can create an object of that class and pass it to tje thread:

```java
new Thread(new YourRunnable()).start();
```

Anonymous classes simplify this:

```java
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        //Your code
    }
}).start();
```

This does the class declaration and instance creation in one step.

In Java 8, lambdas were introduced in order to simplify this even more:

```java
new Thread(()->{
    //Your code
}).start();
```

Note this this works with every interface that only contains a single abstract method.

If you want to make another method with the code that should be run in another thread, you can use method references.

Assuming you have this method:

```java
public void yourTask(){
    //Your code
}
```

You can run it in another thread like this:

```java
new Thread(this::yourTask).start();
```

All of these ways create a new class, those are just simplifications/syntaxtic sugar. The name of the generated classes will be `NameOfOuterClass$numberOfAnonymousClass`, e.g. `YourClass$1`.

Answer (score 0):

`Runnable` is supposed to be implemented by a class, creating a `Thread` from it will execute the method `run()` implemented by that class.

```
public class Jump implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        // Code
    }
}
```

Then on your method you can return a new instance of that Runnable class

```
public Runnable jump() {
    return new Jump();
}
```

You can skip declaring a class and create an annonymous inline Runnable type, like so:

```
public Runnable jump() {
    return new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Code
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The short  answer is that you put the code straight away into the class body (rather than into "public void run()", or - using syntatic sugar - a lambda) . That's just a syntactic error. A more fundamental error is related to a an understanding of concurrency and more specifically how concurrent processes (threads) use shared memory.

The code in th4 seems to assume that "pressedKeys" is under full control of thread th4. It's not. Some thread fills it and (assuming consistency) thread t3 can remove elements at the same time that th4 is processing them (and vice versa). For example, immediately after th4 has established i<pressedKeys.size(), t3 (which runs concurrently) may remove an element of it. th4 then find itself in a spot where pressedKeys.get(i) returns the wrong key or crashes (if i>=pressedKeys.size()).

Google for threads, synchronisation and (eventually) the producer-consumer pattern.